# Android and Akka 2.5 integration

Tags: android, scala, akka, android-r8

I've been trying to use Akka 2.5 in an Android app for a while but didn't succeed at it.
I've encountered many issues :

- **First failure** when using Android standard library was an `IndexOutOfBound` on R8 when referencing `Akka` Methods in `com.android.tools.r8.graph.OffsetToObjectMapping`
- **Second failure** when using [Retrolambda](https://github.com/luontola/retrolambda) was the app that crashes when trying to instantiate an `ActorSystem` with a `ClassNotFoundException` on the `MainActivity`

Has anyone succeeded in using Akka 2.5 with Android ? If yes, how do I do to fully support Akka 2.5 on Android ?